# compare elements of array with a specific string

Tags: batch-file

i am reading a text file line by line with a specific string and then storing each string in array.now i have to compare each array element with a specific string.i have tried with the below code .........

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
for /F "tokens=2,3 delims= " %%a in ('findstr "associationMaxRtx maxIncomingStream maxOutgoingStream initialAdRecWin maxUserdataSize mBuffer nThreshold PathMaxRtx maxInitialRtrAtt minimumRto maximumRto initialRto rtoAlphaIndex tSack" C:\Users\ephajin\logs.txt') do (
     set /A count+=1
     set vartmp1=%%a
     set vartmp2=%%b
     set "array[!count!]="%%a %%b""
)

(FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%count%) DO SET "result=!result! !array[%%a]!"
if %result% == "associationMaxRtx 8"(
echo no need of modification) > result.txt
```

but in result file i am receiving following input:

```
 get . associationMaxRtx 8 associationMaxRtx 8 get . maxIncomingStream 17  maxIncomingStream 17 get . maxOutgoingStream 17 maxOutgoingStream 17 get . initialAdRecWin 32768 initialAdRecWin 32768 maxUserDataSize 1480 maxUserDataSize 1480 get . mBuffer 256 mBuffer 256 get . nThreshold 192 switchbackMinThreshold 1 nThreshold 192 switchbackMinThreshold 1 get . get . maxInitialRtrAtt 8 maxInitialRtrAtt 8 get . minimumRto 10 minimumRto 10 get . maximumRto 40 maximumRto 40 get . initialRto 20 initialRto 20 get . rtoAlphaIndex 3 rtoAlphaIndex 3 get . tSack 4 tSack 4 get tSack
```

in result file all array element is showing in a line why i dont know but it is actually as below:

```
array[0]=get .
array[1]=associationMaxRtx 8   
array[2]=associationMaxRtx 8
```

so on.I have to compare each array element with a specific string for example array[1]="associationMaxRtx 8",and then print a message .How to do this please help me

Comment: Please put a link to the question you are refering to. Also, please format the code.

Comment: Can anybody please help me for the question( http://stackoverflow.com/q/27635227/4369443)

Answer (score 0):

I think a piece of your code is missing above, but for the purposes of removing the extra quotes in the resulting `SET` statement, this will work:

```
(FOR /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%a  IN ('set array[') DO SET "result=%%~b"
ECHO "%result%" ) > result.txt
```

By adding the `~` sign before `b` (making it `%%~b`), the leading and trailing quotes around what `%%b` expands to.

This will yield (for example):

> SET "result=rtoAlphaIndex 3"